# What development technologies are used to develop some particular famous web sites?

Tags: web-applications

What web technologies, like programming-languages, frameworks, libraries, ..etc, were used to develop a particular famous web-service, especially Web2.0s.

For example, Ruby on Rails is used to develop: Odeo, A List Apart, Twitter, 43 Things. ([Source1](http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/best-ruby-on-rails-061307/)) ([Source2](http://www.freecsscart.com/index.php/some-big-websites-that-use-ruby-on-rails/))

PHP is used to develop: Facebook, Photobucket, Wikipedia, Yahoo, Digg. ([Source](http://swik.net/PHP/Major+Sites+that+use+PHP))

And yes, including Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Fairly sure this is a dup, but google-fu is letting me down, can anyone remember the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC

- [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- [Codeplex](http://codeplex.com)
- [MarketWatch](http://www.marketwatch.com/)
- [Restaurantica](http://www.restaurantica.com/)
- [Kbb](http://www.kbb.com/)
- [Ruthschris](http://www.ruthschris.com/)

ASP.NET

- [Monster](http://www.monster.com)
- [Dell](http://www.dell.com)
- [MySpace](http://www.myspace.com)
- [Lego](http://www.lego.com)

Comment: Keep in mind these are not the most visited sites. http://www.alexa.com/topsites contains a decent list of the top visited sites on the internet: If you look at them, I think with the exception of live.com/microsoft.com, none of them are using ASP.NET or some derivative of it.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this site - lots of good info about this topic: http://highscalability.com/
Specifically, this section: http://highscalability.com/links/weblink/24

Comment: Thanks for that site, very valuable information!

Answer (score 2):

This [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/) tells us how SO was built using ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this information about the development of SO.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Google uses Python and GWT for most of its projects.

Comment: AFAIK, GMail **doesn't** use GWT (and I'm not sure they use it that much internally)

Answer (score 1):

PlentyOfFish was built with ASP.NET